# Converting Spherical Vector to Cylindrical Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

Problem:

Given a vector $$v_s=4\vec e_1 + \frac \pi4\vec e_2 + \frac \pi4\vec e_3$$ where $\vec e_1, \vec e_2, \vec e_3$ are spherical basis vectors. Convert this vector into terms of cylindrical basis vectors $\vec e^1,\vec e^2, \vec e^3$.

What I've tried:

Looking at my notes for transforming curvilinear systems, the covariant transformation law is $$\vec e^i = \frac {dq_j}{dq^i}*\vec e_j$$ . I cannot see a way to use this transformation law, so I simply converted the spherical coordinates to cylindrical coordinates:

$$v_c = 4*sin \frac {\pi}4 \vec e^1 + \frac{\pi}4\vec e^2 + 4*cos(\frac{\pi}4)\vec e^3$$

This seems incorrect as I am simply converting a coordinate. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Updated it , thanks